# How to get rid off the blue shade?

Tags: python

Hi I have a problem with my image color. I'm very new to this all but I was trying to follow some tutorials. I want to know how I can get rid off the blue shade over my pictures?

[blue bottle][1]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm

DATADIR = "C:\\Users\woute\Datasets\Garbage classification"

CATEGORIES = ["glass", "cardboard"]

for category in CATEGORIES:  
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  
    for img in os.listdir(path): 
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        plt.imshow(img_array) 
        plt.show()  # display!

        break 
    break 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaZtA.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP0sQ.png
```

Comment: Could you show an example image?

Comment: sadly I cannot upload pictures yet. I'm new to the site so I have to have 10 (points?) reputation. The image is of a bottle that is supposed to be brown but the whole image has a blue shade.

Comment: Do these images look the same or different when you use another image viewer (eg, Gimp, etc)?

Comment: They look different